# How can you test if a certain value is in an instance variable in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to test if an instance variable in my controller contains a specific value. I think .include? would be the way to do it but that doesn't seem to work.

My code looks something like this:

```
@names=Model.find_by_sql("select name from ...") 

if @names.include?(params[:name]) 
    ...
end
```

The if statement somehow allways evaluates to true.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, find_by_sql is not a good way to do. find_by_sql will return you an object of class Model. Whereas params[:name] is most likely a string. The following should work:

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => 'specify conditions here').map(&:name).include?(params[:name])
```

Comment: I changed the code to: `@names=Model.find(:all, :conditions => '...').map(&:name)
if @names.include?(params[:name])` but the .include? allway evaluates to false?

Comment: You should use a debugger to check the values of @names and params[:name]. I'm pretty sure if the array contains the same name as in params[:name], it would return true.

Answer (score 0):

The results of `find_by_sql` will be ([from the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class)):

> an array with columns requested encapsulated as attributes of the model you call this method from.

You need to search within the results.